# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' after property value in object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I got this error when convert json string to javascript object. The json string contains double quotes like `{"Name":"Dem"o"}`
any proper way  to handle double quotes when we parse json string?

Comment: Simply escape the quotes with `\\`.

Answer (score 5):

> The json string contains double quotes like {"Name":"Dem"o"}

That's invalid JSON. You cannot parse it. If you want to be able to parse a string with a JSON parser you need to have valid JSON in the first place. So make sure you have valid JSON:

```
{"Name":"Dem\"o"}
```

To ensure that you never end up with such broken strings, never build them manually - **ALWAYS** use a JSON serializer when creating a JSON string. This will properly handle and escape all values.

Comment: You beat me at photofinish :) +1

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, because the initial answer was: _"That's invalid JSON. You cannot parse it. "_ Not helpful at all.

Comment: @gdoron, no the OP is asking how to parse this JSON string and my answer is that he cannot parse it because he doesn't have a JSON string. He has some arbitrary string. Then I explain how a valid JSON string would have looked like and the proper way to generate it -> by using a JSON serializer. If you think that this doesn't answer the question feel free to downvote it and post a real answer yourself.

Comment: Darin Thanks for reply. I know this is invalid json. I am trying to convert Model to ViewModel in MVC and using knockouts mapping viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonstring, viewModelMapping) so my jsonstring value comes from server . Where I can replace " with \"? server or client side

Comment: The whole point of my answer is that you shouldn't be replacing anything on the client. You should create valid JSON on the server in the first place. Can you show the code where you are manually creating this string so that we can fix it on the server? That's where your problem lies.

Comment: Here is my code var jsonData= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
 
 var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonData,FormMapping);.The 'Model' is c# object which i passed from controller to view

Comment: how i can create valid JSON string at server side?

Comment: Why are you using `ko.mapping.fromJSON`? `jsonData` is not a JSON string. It is a javascript object. So you should use `ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData, FormMapping);`.

Comment: ok suppose this jsonData is json string which comes from server so how to create valid json string at server side?

Comment: What you have shown in your previous comment is not a JSON string. It is a javascript object. There's a fundamental difference between the 2 notions. Also you are mentioning that this is coming from the server. But how? Are you making an AJAX call or something?

Comment: no I have written Html extention method. var jsonstring = '@Html.JsonForModel()';
 viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJSON(jsonstring, viewModelMapping);
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel);. This 'JsonForModel()' extention method converts my model to json string

Comment: public static IHtmlString JsonForModel<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html)
   where TModel : class
  {
   var mapper = new ReflectionMapper();
   var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

   TModel clone = mapper.Map<TModel, TModel>(html.ViewData.Model);
   HtmlEncodeAllStringProperties(clone);

   return new RawString(serializer.Serialize(clone));
  }

Comment: What's this `HtmlEncodeAllStringProperties` function doing? And please stop posting in the comments as the source code is completely unreadable. Go ahead and update your original question.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use below:-

```
addslashes($your_variable);
```

for your case:-

```
addslashes('{"Name":"Dem"o"}');
```